# MySQL view optimization with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am having difficulties in optimizing this SQL statement in MySQL. I have two tables that are populated independently and so the times logged in each table's column will not be the same. What I want is a single table (view) that lists all the records in the sensor_history with the current process information that was present at the sensor's measurement_time. If a process log time was not present, I can live with NULLs in the process fields in the resulting view for that particular record.

What I have here works but it is brute force and woefully inefficient. There are about 500k records in the sensor_history table and about 20k records in the process_history table. I have tried getting my head around different join methods but I run into syntax issues or bad results. I have tried some online optimizers without success and so I am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

For simplicity, I have removed the foreign key relations to other tables. There are no indices in use but feel free to suggest any that may help. Here are the basics:

```
CREATE TABLE `sensor_history` (
  `measurement_time_utc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sensor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sensor_measurement_x` double NOT NULL,
  `sensor_measurement_y` double NOT NULL,
  `sensor_measurement_z` double NOT NULL,
  `sensor_quality` int(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `process_history` (
  `log_time_utc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `process_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `process_speed` double NOT NULL,
  `process_load` int(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW `rollup` AS SELECT
    `sensor_history`.`measurement_time_utc`,
    `sensor_history`.`sensor_id`,
    `sensor_history`.`sensor_measurement_x`,
    `sensor_history`.`sensor_measurement_y`,
    `sensor_history`.`sensor_measurement_z`,
    `sensor_history`.`sensor_quality`,
    (SELECT `process_history`.`process_id` FROM `process_history` WHERE `sensor_history`.`measurement_time_utc`>=`process_history`.`log_time_utc` ORDER BY `process_history`.`log_time_utc` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `process_id`,
    (SELECT `process_history`.`process_speed` FROM `process_history` WHERE `sensor_history`.`measurement_time_utc`>=`process_history`.`log_time_utc` ORDER BY `process_history`.`log_time_utc` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `process_speed`,
    (SELECT `process_history`.`process_load` FROM `process_history` WHERE `sensor_history`.`measurement_time_utc`>=`process_history`.`log_time_utc` ORDER BY `process_history`.`log_time_utc` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `process_load`
    FROM `sensor_history`;
```

How can I make a more efficient rollup view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As written, now many _hours_ does it take to run?  You are writing a query that returns half a million rows??  What will you do with that much data all at once?  There are some things that can improve the performance of the query, but let's trim back the query that way first!

Comment: @RickJames: You hit the nail on the head. Yes, it takes a very long time (single core ARM processor on an embedded field device - long story). The result is actually being called from a PHP web server script and downloaded to an end-user as a CSV file. Eventually, this part will be moved to a cloud-based system but I don't have that luxury right now. I have been wrestling with the requirements (e.g. limit the number of rows, etc.) but the analysts (not computer savvy) need this volume of data all at once. Any thoughts?

Comment: SQL is a champ at analyzing huge volumes of data and delivering summarized data.  Alas, you non-computer-savvy analysts may need your help in achieving it.  Get them to tell you what they _really_ want; then let's see if we can come up with efficient queries to do the task.

Comment: What are the semantics of `measurement_time` and `log_time`?  Perhaps the first is "when the reading was taken"?  And the second is when it was `INSERTed` into the table (which can be delayed due to network issues)?  It looks like the three subqueries could be done as a single query.  However, they are 'correlated', and I am having trouble wrapping my head around the times.

Comment: measurement_time_utc is the seconds since 1/1/1970 that the sensor device took the reading. The sensor has a storage mechanism but I need to "empty the bucket" every 10 minutes - that is, I issue a command to get the history and write it to my sensor_history table. I empty the sensors' bucket on a successful write to the db. measurement_time_utc is sourced by the sensor device but I time-sync it every so often with my system. My system sources the log_time_utc in the process_history. I am ok with drift < 1sec but typically I only see about 1ms difference.

Comment: And how often does the sensor have a new reading?  That is, what is the delta between measurement_time_utc values?

Comment: Anywhere from 5 second to 3600 second intervals. Most land about 10 or 60 seconds - it's the analysts' decision and it is tweaked every few days (or weeks) based on the situation and external factors. Eventually, this will be semi-automated as we get smarter on this. To complete the equation, there may be 24 to 48 different sensor IDs for the next year or two, then potentially subject to change. For sensors that are deemed non-important for a while, the analyst will change the polling interval to 3600 sec just to keep the BIST features intact.

Comment: Process IDs change maybe 50 times a day but there could be bursts of busy activity or a few days with very little activity. Again, this is something we are trying to dial in. It depends on the deployment scenario and is very fluid.

Comment: So, the dataset may be 1GB after several months, probably slowing down after that.  So, my concern about a "huge" db is not well-founded.  However, summary information will get slower and slower unless something is done, such as [_Summary tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

Comment: So, the subqueries are getting the first speed and load after after a given sensor timestamp?

Comment: I have another cron job that looks at all of my tables and purges any entries older than 14 days. This is to ensure that disk space (eMMC) stays about 40% free and provides enough margin for wear-levelling.  After about a year's worth of use, these devices come in for service and we evaluate or recondition them for re-deployment. And, yes, the subqueries' purpose is to note the last known process information at the time the measure was taken. The analyst needs to know the process that was in use at the time the sensor took a reading.

Comment: The tables I noted above have been greatly simplified. There are about 20 fields in the sensor_history table and about 15 fields in the process_history table. The rollup (merged view) would show all 20 sensor_history fields and about 10 process_history fields. This is just for the download-to-CSV requirement. I have started to make this table on the fly as sensor measurements come in as you suggested. It looks promising.

Comment: Thanks.  When you use `rollup`, will there be a `WHERE` clause?  Or other qualifications?  Without any `WHERE`, I seen how to simplify it, but I worry that would not work.

Comment: The 'WHERE' may come at the very end of the query and if there is one, would probably be either specifying a range of sensors IDs or a time range. Most likely there would not be any as the analyst would grab everything and then use a post-download tool to sort, manage, and interpret the data. I plan on avoiding the WHERE clause for now since they have indicated it would not be needed for 90% (or higher) of the use cases.

Comment: Keep in mind that the query will be slower and slower as the table grows bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Views are really hard to optimize in MySQL.  Your best hope is for an index on:

```
process_history(log_time_utc, process_id, process_speed)
```

The last two columns are included so the index covers the query and doesn't need to refer to the data pages.

Answer (score 0):

While you are trying to figure out what the Analysts really need, let's do some improvements that are easier to do now than later.

`DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes and delivers about 16 significant digits.  That is gross overkill for every sensor I have heard of.  Consider the 4-byte `FLOAT`, which gives you about 7 significant digits.

(Where am I going with this?  Capturing "sensor" data keeps coming, and it eventually fills up disk and that makes it slow.  So, let's shrink things soon.)

`INT` is 4 bytes and has a range of +/- 2 billion.  Are you expecting that many sensors?  How about a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` with a range of 0..255?  Or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED (1-bytes, range 0..64K)?  Ditto for any other ids.

Or... Do you really need to save all the data?  Maybe day-old data can be summarized down to hourly min, max, avg, etc?  And month-old data is needed only to a day's resolution?

We have lots to discuss once your analysts explain to you what the *do* want.  Then you need to read-between-the-lines to see what they *will* want.  (I can help there, too.)

Comment: I like where this is going. Double -> float is a smart idea and I will implement that. There was just some legacy baggage as well as some background calculations (e.g. FFTs) that used doubles. IDs can be reduced to two unsigned bytes and that will help. I had just assumed that a natural int (32-bit processor) was faster but I think the storage outweighs that.

Comment: Just FYI, the example tables above have been greatly simplified for this discussion. We have multiple types of sensors (vibration, temperature, pressure, radiation, speed, etc.) that are fused later on. They are also in remote, inaccessible areas so they may collect a week's worth of data before an analyst can perform the data exfil. I am discussing with them now what they absolutely need. In the short term, I wrote a C/C++ app using mysqli API that builds the CSV file; it runs periodically in the background as a cron job.

Comment: @prcarp - It is OK to provide a `FLOAT` to something that calculates in `DOUBLE`.  All columns in the database are assumed to be byte-aligned; there is no extra benefit of "word" alignment.  Even if there were, it be vanishingly insignificant in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @prcarp - and as for the loading...  I would prefer to build multi-row `INSERTs` and get the data inserted as it comes in.  100 rows at a time is almost as good as a csv file.  Since your ingestion process is well in hand, the `FOREIGN KEYs` are checking for problems that won't happen.

Comment: That is actually what I started working on today: build the CSV content on-the-fly as the data comes in. The tricky part is that there may be multiple sensor clients polling other sensor types and building different table content that will ultimately need to contribute to the CSV content. They will all have to follow the same rules. A bit complex but do-able. At one point I was considering NOSQL/MongoDB for this type of thing but opted against it.   BTW, still waiting on some feedback from the analysts....

Comment: I shy away from nosql-types; they tend to (1) do things by brute force, hence be limited to disk speed, and/or (2) have you re-invent SQL.